# Need to convert VARCHAR(10) using MMMDD string into a DATE in SQL

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012, varchar

I am making a report that shows the departments birthdays for the current month, and for some reason they decided to use VARCHAR(10) for the employee's birthday in the table.

While, I can get the information I need using VARCHAR, I am unable to filter by current month in Tableau because it does not recognize the data as an actual date.

So I need to convert VARCHAR(10) using MMMDD string into a DATE in SQL. I know without the year it would never be a valid date, but the year is unimportant to my report, so a generic year can be applied.

Any Help would be awesome. PeopleSoftData.birth_date  is the field that is VARCHAR(10) and the data string is using MMMDD Ex:JAN18 without a year, so I've been having trouble converting to a DATE using pre-existing Q&A on the site.

```
SELECT
    PeopleSoftData.fname+' '+PeopleSoftData.lname AS 'Full Name',
    PeopleSoftData.fname AS 'First Name',
    PeopleSoftData.lname AS 'Last Name',
    PeopleSoftData.location AS 'Site',
    PeopleSoftData.birth_date AS 'Birth Date', -- This field is VARCHAR(10) and the data string is using MMMDD Ex:JAN18 without a year
    PeopleSoftData.orig_hire_date AS 'Hire Date',
    PeopleSoftData.supervisor_name AS 'Supervisor'

FROM dbo.USC_StatsApp_Members MemberList
    INNER JOIN dbo.USC_Reporting_PeopleSoft_Data PeopleSoftData ON (PeopleSoftData.empcontid = MemberList.empcontid)

WHERE 
    PeopleSoftData.termination_date IS NULL
    AND PeopleSoftData.birth_date IS NOT NULL
    AND MemberList.USC_Active = 1
    AND DATEDIFF(wk,MemberList.Last_seen_PeopleSoft,current_timestamp) < 2
```

Comment: Don't forget to have a leap year as generic year.

Comment: Why do you even need to cast it as a date? Are you just trying to change the display format?

Comment: to execute date functions on it....

Comment: @CharlesBretana Since OP doesn't care about the year I'm curious which functions are relevant. `monthname()`?

Comment: We use Tableau to generate visual reports and since I need to separate the birthdays by months logically, it's best to do it in SQL rather than Tableau. I've already informed the developers to convert that table into DATETIME so we don't have to do this.

Comment: Well if you're trying to create a calendar view then the year will matter. (Of course you already know that.) I personally wouldn't make the argument that they need to change the type. If they do change it it should be `date` not `datetime`.

Comment: Not making a calendar view. The recipient of the report just needs to see Month and Day of the employee's birthday for the current month for his monthly newsletter. I just needed it converted into a date so I can filter by current month in Tableau.

Comment: @shawnt00,  "I am unable to filter by current month in Tableau"

Comment: Somehow I overlooked the "current month" part. While you could have done the filtering as something like `birthdate like upper(left(monthname(getdate()), 3)) + '%'` it's certainly easier to format the output once you have a real date to work with. I've seen many developers forget about the leap year problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can help

```
select cast(concat('JAN18',' ',year(getdate())) as date)
```

Returns 2016-01-18

Comment: Thanks, that got me what i needed using: CAST(CONCAT(PeopleSoftData.birth_date,' ',year(getdate())) as date) AS 'Birth Date',

Comment: Will not work next year (2017), for FEB29. Stick to leap years,

Comment: @jarlh You are absolutely correct, the default year should be a leap year.  I saw your comment and should have stressed it as well

Answer (score 0):

just concatenate current year to the beginning of it and cast it to a date

```
SELECT
   p.fname+' '+PeopleSoftData.lname AS 'Full Name',
   p.fname AS 'First Name',
   p.lname AS 'Last Name',
   p.location AS 'Site',
   cast(datename(year, getdate()) + p.birth_date as date) AS 'Birth Date', 
   p.orig_hire_date AS 'Hire Date',
   p.supervisor_name AS 'Supervisor'

FROM dbo.USC_StatsApp_Members m
    JOIN dbo.USC_Reporting_PeopleSoft_Data p
   ON p.empcontid = m.empcontid

WHERE p.termination_date IS NULL
   AND p.birth_date IS NOT NULL
   AND m.USC_Active = 1
   AND DATEDIFF(wk, m.Last_seen_PeopleSoft, current_timestamp) < 2
```

to eliminate errors you can test first...

```
SELECT
   p.fname+' '+PeopleSoftData.lname AS 'Full Name',
   p.fname AS 'First Name',
   p.lname AS 'Last Name',
   p.location AS 'Site',
   case When isDate(datename(year, getdate()) + p.birth_date) = 1 
        then cast(datename(year, getdate()) + p.birth_date as date)
        else null end AS 'Birth Date', 
   p.orig_hire_date AS 'Hire Date',
   p.supervisor_name AS 'Supervisor'

FROM dbo.USC_StatsApp_Members m
    JOIN dbo.USC_Reporting_PeopleSoft_Data p
   ON p.empcontid = m.empcontid

WHERE p.termination_date IS NULL
   AND p.birth_date IS NOT NULL
   AND m.USC_Active = 1
   AND DATEDIFF(wk, m.Last_seen_PeopleSoft, current_timestamp) < 2
```

Comment: oh, missed that.  Then, duh, concatenate *current year* to it.... I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way ('FEB29' => '29FEB2016 => DATETIME):

```
select cast(right(birth_date, 2) + left(birth_date, 3) + '2016' as date)
```

> 2016-02-29

Comment: Thanks. Since 2016 is a leap year, this would work to keep it in check! Learning a lot! I'm such a SQL novice, lol.